# the meaning of corr=F in the print command

Tags: r

I am learning how to build GLMM model using R. With respect to the following script, what does the argument of `corr=F` stand for in the print command?

```
dative.glmm1 <- lmer(RealizationOfRecipient ~ SemanticClass +
LengthOfRecipient + AnimacyOfRec + DefinOfRec + PronomOfRec + AccessOfRec +
LengthOfTheme + AnimacyOfTheme + DefinOfTheme + PronomOfTheme + AccessOfTheme +
(1|Speaker) + (1|Verb), family="binomial")

print(dative.glmm1, corr=F)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the help file on `mer-class` objects, we see:

> correlation    logical - should the correlation matrix of the
>   fixed-effects parameter estimates be printed? Defaults to TRUE.

So `corr` is expanded to `correlation` and simply controls whether the matrix is printed.

Comment: thanks, I searched help document for print, but looks like it does not include the option of "corr"

Comment: @user785099 `print` has many methods. `?print` only shows you the generic method. When you call `print` it on a `mer` object a separate function is called, not `print.default`. Go to `?lmer` and then click on the linked text for `mer`.